# Dimension too large error when trying to shade, but not before

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

The following code runs nicely and produces an image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={16, 17, 19, 20}, labelOnlyB={1, 5, 7}, labelOnlyC={6, 12}, labelOnlyAC={15, 18}, labelOnlyBC={3, 9}, labelNotABC={2, 4, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14}, radius=2.5cm, overlap=1.25cm, vgap=2cm, hgap=3cm]
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

This code, in which only one line has been added (\fillOnlyB) results in a "dimension too large" error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={16, 17, 19, 20}, labelOnlyB={1, 5, 7}, labelOnlyC={6, 12}, labelOnlyAC={15, 18}, labelOnlyBC={3, 9}, labelNotABC={2, 4, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14}, radius=2.5cm, overlap=1.25cm, vgap=2cm, hgap=3cm]
\fillOnlyB
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

Why was the error generated when trying to colour but not before, and more importantly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem to be an interplay between the allowed values for the  `radius` and `overlap` to make a successful identification of the area.

So the way should be to choose a nice overlap and decrease the radius until everything works.

Using   `overlap=2.5cm`  and `radius =2.5cm`

[image: c]

With `overlap=1.5cm` and `radius =2.3cm`

[image: d]

Comment: Yup, that did it. Strange!